# Arraylist turns empty when having contact with listener

Tags: java, arraylist, actionlistener, is-empty

Hello I am writing a program for school and I am stuck on this problem where I try to get an arraylist from another class using a button, but when the arraylist comes in contact with the listener it becomes empty. If i try to use the arraylist in another function instead of the listener itself it is still empty.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class addPanel {
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JButton OKButton;
    private JButton registreerButton;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private String voorNaam;
    private String achterNaam;

    public addPanel() {

        textField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyReleased(e);
                voorNaam = textField1.getText().toLowerCase();
            }
        });
        textField2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyReleased(e);
                achterNaam = textField2.getText().toLowerCase();
            }
        });
        OKButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println(gebruikas); // is empty
                returnInputGebruiker();
            }
        });
    }
    Gebruikers g = new Gebruikers();
    ArrayList<Gebruiker> gebruikas = g.getGebruikers();
    
    public void worksFine() {
        System.out.println(gebruikas);//works fine on its own
    }

    public void returnInputGebruiker(){

        System.out.println(gebruikas);// is empty
    }

    public void run(JFrame parent) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(panel1);
        frame.setTitle("persoon details");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        if (parent != null)
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried putting the getter in different places but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How exactly does the array list "become empty?"  What steps do you perform on the GUI to reproduce the error?

Comment: Aside from main question please *don't name your class as `addPanel`* as it looks like *method* since it (1) starts in lower case instead of upper case, (2) is verb (action) instead of noun (name of something, like `MyPanel`, `MyPanel`, etc.). Also since you want help with debugging, please provide code which we could debug. But to debug code we first need to be able to run it. So please provide actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (a.k.a. [MCVE]).

Comment: Please provide the definitions of your `Gebruikers` and `Gebruiker` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to make "Gebruikers list" static and access it using the class name in the listener?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).